# ASP classic & SQL (Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.)

Tags: sql, asp-classic

Getting this error when trying to add a new group using the information entered by the user.

```
Microsoft Access Database Engine error '80040e14'

Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

/student/s0190204/wip/group-add.asp, line 79
```

This is the sql, the session is getting the ID of the user logged in.

```
sql_comd="INSERT INTO group (grp_USERID, grp_name, grp_caption, grp_content, grp_DATECREATED, grp_OPEN) VALUES('" &_
session("usr_ID") & "','" & _
request("grp_name") & "','" & _
request("grp_caption") & "','" & _
request("grp_content") & "','" & _
date & "','" & _
request("grp_open") & "')"
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the solution offered on your other question?

Comment: Is it possible that one of the variables you are putting in the query contains an apostrophe? This would cause an error.

Comment: This will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: What does `response.write( sql_comd )` show?

Comment: Did you try printing out your sql_comd string value to see the completly formatted statement?

Comment: Have ou tried `[group]`?

Comment: I think you should look at parametrized queries (doable with ADODB.Command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you trace this through, and post the output string that you're passing directly to SQL.  Just put a breakpoint in there right as the string is created and check it out.

There's not much wrong with this code, persay, but you haven't made sure that your input strings are clean.  It's probable that they have a quotation mark in them or the date isn't in the proper string format and so on.

Additionally, note that this query is highly susceptible to query injection because it seems to stuff input directly from the request through to the database.

OH, and.  Your 'Insert INTO' needs Group in []. (like [Group])  And your dates should probably be DateTimes instead of strings. (if this works with just the brackets)  See my note on your other question. (And avoid using these (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in your schema)

And you can set the 'default' of the date to '=GetDate()' instead of passing it through from the C# side, which I personally prefer.